# GRAV: ERROR Missing .dependencies file in user/ folder

Tags: grav

I'm trying to setup Grav CMS

When i run

```
php bin/grav install
```

I get the error

```
ERROR Missing .dependencies file in user/ folder
```

I'm using ubuntu with nginx serving php 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had downloaded the **.zip** file with the CMS, and extracted/manually copied to the `www` directory.

So hidden files were not copied.

```
.dependencies
.htaccss
```

using `ls -l -a` in the folder where you extracted the files originally `Dowloads/grav` I could see the files that were not copied to fix it

```
cp .dependencies .htaccss /var/www/grav/
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this problem is all to common when copying files :(

When I install GRAV on my server each time, I always copy the Zip file to the server, unzip it in place, then remove the zip file - using this method I have never had a problem with the installing of GRAV

HTH
Rich